# django-tables2 : target="_blank" is not rendered

Tags: python, rendering, django-tables2

I wrote as suggested in documentation this class to render url columns :

```
class MyTable(ColumnShiftTable):
    uri = tables.URLColumn()

from django.utils.html import format_html
class URLColumn(tables.Column):
    def render(self, value):
        return format_html('<a href="%s" target="_blank">%s</a>' % value)
```

But the _blank target does not appear in the page source code, only the href does. It could be a Django issue or a django-tables2, I didn't find yet why.

Comment: `django-tables2` already has `Column` subclass to display urls: https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/api-reference.html#django_tables2.columns.LinkColumn

Comment: @mingaleg thanks, I didn't see that : RTFA.. I know. And actually, the LinkColumn is obsolete. The linkify parameter is to be used now : "This column should not be used anymore, the linkify keyword argument to regular columns can be used achieve the same results." and still no external _blank target.

Comment: https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2/issues/313#issuecomment-200748550

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found my way with the TemplateColumn :

```
uri = tables.TemplateColumn('<a href="{{record.uri}}" target="_blank">{{record.uri}}</a>')
```